# On Mac OS, can apps with screen recording permission still record your screen even when they're not open?

Tags: macos, permission, privacy

On Mac OS, can apps with screen recording permission still record your screen even when they're not open?

Or do they no longer have the ability to screen record once you've quit them?  (That is, they wouldn't have the ability until you open them again.)

Comment: What is causing you to suspect otherwise? Please provide some context.

Comment: Just something I was wondering about.  I wasn't sure one way or another.

Answer (score 1):

No, they can't record your screen once you quit them unless they you have allowed them to run in the background. You can check that in *System Settings > General > Login Items*.

Note that when you quit apps that are allowed to run in the background, they look as if they aren't running (no dot beneath them in dock) but they are. You can quit an app running in the background through a menu usually present in the app or by force quitting it.

Comment: Thanks.  So as long as you open an app and quit it from within the app itself, you can be assured that it's no longer running (and that it won't be able to record your screen)?

Comment: @A.Ro Yes. You can also force quit the app, it'll also work.